# when I install brew,the terminal showed zsh: parse error near `JIA/.zprofile'

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, neovim, lunarvim

When I'm trying to install homebrew on my M1 mac, it shows zsh: parse error near `JIA/.zprofile'

I ran

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then the terminal displays

```
zsh: parse error near `JIA/.zprofile'
```

Here is a screenshot of my terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsIDk.png)

Answer (score 3):

Your last try is almost right. You have either to escape the space in your home's path or put it in quotes.

Try

```bash
(echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> "/Users/Yunnis JIA/.zprofile"
```